# Matching a string with cell in CSV file and returning adjacent cells

Tags: python, csv, match

I have the following code:

```
for i in self.jobs:
    with open('postcodes.csv', 'rb') as f:                
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == self.jobs[i][3]:
                self.jobs[i].append((row[1],row[2]))
            else:
                self.jobs[i].append('lat & lng not available)
```

My problem is this produces "lat & lng not available" for each row in the csv file, I only want to know if it matches give me the info from the adjacent two rows, if it doesn't, give me the 'lat & lng not available'.

See http://pastebin.com/gX5HtJV4 for full code

SSCCE could be as follows:

```
reader = [('HP2 4AA', '51.752927', '-0.470095'), ('NE33 3GA', '54.991663', '-1.414911'), ('CV1 1FL','52.409463', '-1.509234')]
selfjobs = ['NE33 3AA', 'CV1 1FL', 'HP2 4AA']

latlng = []

for row in reader:
    for i in selfjobs:
        if i in row[0]:
            latlng.append((row[1],row[2]))
        else:
            latlng.append(('not available','not available'))    

print latlng
```

Following Martineau's help in the comments, this is the code I ended up with:

```
for i in self.jobs:
        job = self.jobs[i]
        postcode = job[3]
        home = (54.764919,-1.368824)
        with open('postcodes.csv', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                postcode_csv = row[0]
                if postcode in postcode_csv:
                    job.append((row[1], row[2]))
            else:
                 job.append(home)
```

Comment: Any more context would be useful. At the moment it is not clear what actually all those variables are.

Comment: @kroolik edited the main question, thanks

Comment: What is the `type` of `self.jobs`' entries? Does it match the ones from the `row`?

Comment: Are you sure there is at least one postcode in `self.jobs` matching another postcode in your csv file? Does `self.jobs[i][3]` return a string value so it can be properly compared to `row[0]`?

Comment: @aleksander Lidtke self.jobs is a dictionary, it has a list of jobs say. for example... 1 might look like this {1['job','location','postcode'...]} so jobs[i][3] always returns a postcode, which is what i want to match in the first column of the csv file.

Comment: Are you asking how to craft the algorithm? It looks like you have to finagl some data to deal with present data, past, and the next line. It looks like you are going to need to cache three lines from the file at any given time. Obviously, for the first line, there is no previous line, and likewise for the last line, there is no next line. Python achieves laziness through list comprehensions. You'll need those, and even if you don't because the file is short, they are useful constructs.

Comment: Postcodes as strings, you mean? Because they need to match their types (`row[0]` will be a string).

Comment: @ecampver yeah certain, if I take out the else statement it works perfectly providing all of the postcodes are in the 1st column of the csv file, as soon as I put a postcode in that isn't in the csv file though it throws up an error.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so everyone doesn't have to keep guessing about what you mean.

Comment: @martineau I've put a link to pastebin of the full code, hope that's ok

Comment: You say this in one of your comments: `{1:['job','location','postcode'...]} so jobs[i][3] always returns a postcode`, but the postcode is actually `jobs[1][2]`, isn't it? I mean, the postcode is the third element but the index number 2.

Comment: @ecampver I just used that as an example, my actual code has it at [3].  I've tried a few different things now and still haven't worked it out...

Comment: That's not really a SSCCE. Anyway, I'd suggest verifying that the string value that ends up in `jobs[i][3]` in the `jobs` list of lists actually matches one of the values in the first column of at least one of the rows in the `postcodes.csv` file. Also your code would be more readable if you assigned names to the integer constants so you could write things like `self.jobs[i][POSTCODE]` -- it would also help prevent using the wrong index values.

Comment: @martineau I've tried it with working postcodes.  I get the following appended into my lists:
['HP2 4AA', 'NE33 3GA', 'CV1 1FL', 'EN1 1TH', 'WD17 2BD']
[('51.752927', '-0.470095'), ('54.991663', '-1.414911'), ('52.409463', '-1.509234'), ('51.652721', '-0.052857'), ('51.65142', '-0.387664')], which are the correct lat and longs for the corresponding postcodes.
I didn't think of assigning names but I will do, but I'm still left with the same problem...

Comment: Your questions says you get "lat & lng not available" for each row in the csv file. Anyway, what I meant was, for at least one sublist of `self.jobs`, print out the value of `self.jobs[i][3]` as well as that of every `row[0]` value read from the `postcodes.csv` file.

Comment: If i take out the else statement it works fine and gives me the result I mentioned... I'm trying to do a proper SSCCE now. thanks for the help in the mean time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at least part of the problem is that you actually have the following in your pastebin code:

```
    for i in self.jobs:
        with open('postcodes.csv', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row[0] == self.jobs[i][3]:
                    self.jobs[i].append((row[1], row[2]))
                elif self.jobs[i][3] != row[0]:
                    self.jobs[i].append("nothing")
```

However, since the`i`in the`for i in self.jobs`loop is itself a`list`, it can't be used as a index into`self.jobs` like that. Instead, I think it would make more sense to be doing something like the following in the loop:

```
    for job in self.jobs:
        with open('postcodes.csv', 'rb') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                if row[0] == job[3]:
                    job.append((row[1], row[2]))
                    break
            else: # no match
                job.append("nothing")
```

...which only indexes the fields of data in the rows read in from the csv file. For efficiency, it stops reading the file as soon as it finds a match. If it ever reads through whole file without finding a match, it appends`"nothing"`to indicate this, which is what the`else`clause of the inner`for`loop is doing.

BTW, it also seems rather inefficient to open and potentially read through the entire`postcodes.csv` file for every entry in`self.jobs`, so you might want to consider reading the whole thing into a dictionary, once, *before* executing the`for job in self.jobs:`loop (assuming the file's not too large for that).

Comment: You cracked it, I can't believe it was as simple as the 'else' being in the wrong place! It needed to be on the same indent as the 'for' not the 'if'.  The postcodes.csv file is 71MB so I'm not sure that's feasible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @martineau One of the things that's puzzled me is how does Python deal with a lot of data if you read it all in? In other words, is there a way to read all the data in and have it be lazy?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: If you read all of the data in, then it'll consume however much memory is necessary to store it some sort of data structure. It may be possible to only read portions of it in at once and/or put off doing so until it's actually needed. Python has a `shelve` module which is a persistent disk-based dictionary-like object that's something like that. However, since memory is fairly cheap and plentiful nowadays, reading a 71MB csv file isn't really something to be too concerned about (and very likely much faster the reading though it completely multiple times).

Comment: Paul: The `else` is really only a minor simplification -- the main problem was trying to index `self.jobs` with `i` which was a list not an integer index.

Comment: @martineau I put the postcodes csv file into a dictionary at the start of my program and it is much faster now so thanks for that!

Comment: That's good news, and you're welcome. BTW, would you please consider also up-voting my answer if you think it's worthy?